# Generate ordered tuples of infinite sequences

Tags: python, generator

I have two generators `genA` and `genB` and each of them generates an infinite, strictly monotonically increasing sequence of integers.

Now I need a generator that generates all tuples `(a, b)` such that `a` is produced by `genA` and `b` is produced by `genB` and `a < b`, ordered by `a + b` ascending. In case of ambiguity the ordering is of no importance, i.e. if `a + b == c + d`, it doesn't matter if it generates `(a, b)` first or `(c, d)` first.

For instance. If both `genA` and `genB` generate the prime numbers, then the new generator should generate:

```
(2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5), (2, 7), (3, 7), (5, 7), (2, 11), ...
```

If `genA` and `genB` were finite lists, zipping and then sorting would do the trick.

Apparenyly for all tuples of form `(x, b)` the following holds: `first(genA) <= x <= max(genA,b) <= b`, being `first(genA)` the first element generated by `genA` and `max(genA,b)` the last element generated by `genA` which is less than `b`.

This is how far I have gotten. Any ideas of how to combine two generators in the described manner?

Comment: You say that for finite lists, it can be achieved by using `zip`, but that only generates tuples `(a0,b0), (a1,b1)` and so on. Shouldn't that be [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? This will generate `(a0, b0), (a0, b1), ..., (a1, b0), ...`

Comment: @BasSwinckels True. I was unprecise using the word "zip". I was thinking about something like `[ (a, b) for a in listA for b in listB if a < b]`.

Comment: Is there any more information you can give about `genA` and `genB`? Will they always be the same generator? Will you have a closed form for the sequence? (obviously not if they are primes)

Comment: `genA` are indeed primes, and `genB` are sums of primes.

Comment: as in the nth element in `genB` is the sum of the first n primes?

Comment: @axblount No. But actually a general solution for arbitrary generators would be interesting.

Comment: The solution from @BasSwinckels should work for all generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this without saving all the results from `genA`. A solution might look something like this:

```
import heapq
def gen_weird_sequence(genA, genB):
    heap = []
    a0 = next_a = next(genA)
    saved_a = []
    for b in genB:
        while next_a < b:
            saved_a.append(next_a)
            next_a = next(genA)
        # saved_a now contains all a < b
        for a in saved_a:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (a+b, a, b)) #decorate pair with sorting key a+b
        # (minimum sum in the next round) > b + a0, so yield everything smaller
        while heap and heap[0][0] <= b + a0:
            yield heapq.heappop(heap)[1:] # pop smallest and undecorate
```

Explanation: The main loop iterates simply over all elements in `genB`, and then gets all elements from `genA` that are smaller than `b` and saves them in a list. It then generates all the tuples `(a0, b), (a1, b), ..., (a_n, b)` and stores them in a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_heap), which is an efficient data-structure when you are only interested in extracting the minimum value of a collection. As with sorting, you can do the [trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to not save the pairs itself, but prepend them with the value you want to sort on (`a+b`), since comparisons between tuples will start by comparing the first item. Finally, it pops all the elements off the heap for which the sum is guaranteed smaller than the sum of any pair generated for the next `b` and yields them.

Note that both `heap` and `saved_a` will increase while you are generating results, I guess proportionally to the square root of the number of elements generated so far.

Quick test with some primes:

```
In [2]: genA = (a for a in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19])
In [3]: genB = (b for b in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19])
In [4]: for pair in gen_weird_sequence(genA, genB): print pair
(2, 3)
(2, 5)
(3, 5)
(2, 7)
(3, 7)
(5, 7)
(2, 11)
(3, 11)
(2, 13)
(3, 13)
(5, 11)
(5, 13)
(7, 11)
(2, 17)
(3, 17)
(7, 13)
```

as expected. Test with infinite generators:

```
In [11]: from itertools import *
In [12]: list(islice(gen_weird_sequence(count(), count()), 16))
Out[12]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (0, 4), (1, 3), (0, 5), (1, 4),
          (2, 3), (0, 6), (1, 5), (2, 4), (0, 7), (1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```